# Send PHP form info to 2 diferent emails (one fixed and the other for the user)

Tags: php

I have the following problem: I am making a website for a university project, which has a PHP form that works correctly, however, I need to send this form info not only to a specific email but also to the user who completes the form.

It only have 3 fields (name, email and city), and from a php I rescue those 3 fields from a PHP with the following code:

```
  <?php
$errorMSG = "";

if (empty($_POST["nombre"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Nombre requerido ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["nombre"];
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Email requerido ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

if (empty($_POST["ciudad"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Ciudad requerida ";
} else {
    $message = $_POST["ciudad"];
}

/*if (empty($_POST["terms"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Terms is required ";
} else {
    $terms = $_POST["terms"];
}*/


$EmailTo = "yo@prueba.com";
$Subject = "Nuevo mensaje del museo virtual";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Nombre: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Ciudad: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";
/*$Body .= "Terms: ";
$Body .= $terms;
$Body .= "\n"; */

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "Mensaje enviado y link despachado";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Error en el envío :(";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}
?>
```

How do I rescue the $email variable to add it inside the $Emailto variable and be able to send the form to the user and administrator emails?

Thank you for any help you can bring me!!

Comment: just call `mail()` again with whatever parameters you want to use

Comment: For example `$success = mail($email, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code to enable you send the message to the user who completes the form.

You can specify an email to serve as the sender of the message by modifying the 'From: ' section of the mail function. Currently, the sender shows as the email of the user who completes the form.

```
<?php
$errorMSG = "";

if (empty($_POST["nombre"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Nombre requerido ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["nombre"];
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Email requerido ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

if (empty($_POST["ciudad"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Ciudad requerida ";
} else {
    $message = $_POST["ciudad"];
}

/*if (empty($_POST["terms"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Terms is required ";
} else {
    $terms = $_POST["terms"];
}*/


$EmailTo = "yo@prueba.com";
$Subject = "Nuevo mensaje del museo virtual";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Nombre: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Ciudad: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";
/*$Body .= "Terms: ";
$Body .= $terms;
$Body .= "\n"; */

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// send email to user
$success_user = mail($email, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);


// redirect to success page
if ($success && $success_user && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "Mensaje enviado y link despachado";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Error en el envío :(";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}
?>
```